# Craft 3: White blank page when accessing website and Craft login page

Tags: craft3

I'm getting white blank page when trying to access my website and Craft login page. I haven't updated the website for few months. So I assume no files has been changed.

I checked with the hosting provider, and they say everything is okay on their part.

I turned on dev mode, but still get a blank page.

What could possibly cause this? Is there anything I need to check? Thank you in advance. It's on Craft CMS 3.1.28. The url is https://vispaleis-oostende.be/.

Edit: as commented on a below answer: When I change the contents of Craft's index.php file to echo some text, this text does get shown on the website. Also, when I create such an echo php-file and include it from other folders using the variables CRAFT_BASE_PATH or CRAFT_VENDOR_PATH, it also shows that text. So the domain does point to the correct location, the index.php file gets loaded (also on any 'subpage' and the CMS-url, so not only the index page) and the include paths are found.

Edit 2: I just linked the domain name back to the beta-server, since everything was still working there. I also copied the database, to reflect the changes made in the CMS (small text changes). No files were changed since going online, so I didn't need to copy any files. Everything works as expected on the beta-server, so I think it's a problem on the 'live' server, even though the hosting provider claims it isn't. If anyone has an idea what this could be, please let me know so I can get back to the hosting provider...

Answer (score 1):

Based on the response headers:

[image]

It doesn't look like the response is coming from Craft at all, so I think it's likely that you should contact your hosting provider again.

To me, it seems like the domain isn't pointing at the right place for your website hosting, because Craft isn't even fielding the request.

Comment: When I change the contents of Craft's index.php file to echo some text, this text does get shown on the website. Also, when I create and include such an echo php-file in other folders, using the variables CRAFT_BASE_PATH or CRAFT_VENDOR_PATH, it also shows that text. So it does point to the correct location, the index.php file gets loaded (on any 'subpage', so not only the index) and the include paths are found.

Comment: Very strange. Do you have the `.htaccess` file in place, and named properly?

Comment: The evidence suggests that this is hosting-related. I'd ask them to do a bit more to earn your business, or find another one https://nystudio107.com/blog/web-hosting-for-agencies-freelancers

Comment: Thanks Andrew! I'll try with the hosting company again.